# Reading IPTC information Django

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, python-imaging-library

I have published my django project on shared hosting, there are no problems at all. Everything seems to work as it should, but as soon as the system is to read IPTC information from images, it does not work. I get absolutely no errors, but it doesn't read the information. But in the local development server on my macbook it works without problems, then it reads the iptc information. Both use the same code, the same python version and the same Pillow.

What should I do?

I have tried to change the code a bit, but to no avail.

Comment: You should read [ask] and [mcve] then click [edit] and update your question.